# R: generalised additive model on proportional data

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, proportion, generalized-additive-model, unevenly-spaced-time-series

## Introduction

I am analysing temporal population data on the amphipod *Orchestia gammarellus*. At several moments each year, all animals were collected from a small spot, and several life history traits were measured. For these traits, I want to know whether there are seasonality and/or trends. I have data since mid 2014.

In this example, I focus on the proportion of reproductively active females in each sample. This peaks every year around July, so I would expect to find seasonality.

The data have been collected irregularly, so I thought time series analysis to be inappropriate. Rather, I have read good things about Generalised Additive Models (GAMs), and am trying to use them in R. No luck so far (see below).

## Methods

### Study system

Animals are collected from the grazed salt marsh on the island of Schiermonnikoog, a barrier island in the north of the Netherlands. This is the western part of the salt marsh, which is grazed by cattle. The cattle eat primarily *Elytrigia atherica*, but shun the tougher *Juncus gerardii*. This creates patches of "high vegegation" *J. gerardii* habitat, in which the soil is loose, amidst a sea of "low vegetation" *E. atherica* habitat, where the soil is compacted by trampling.

In comparison, the eastern part of the salt marsh is ungrazed, and there are no mosaics of vegetation types. Here the soil is much looser, and densities of amphipods much higher.

### Animals

The amphipod *Orchestia gammarellus* is a keystone species in European salt marshes. Through burrowing small tunnels, it changes soil nutrient levels, stimulates soil development, promotes soil oxygen conditions and impacts vegetation succession. However, on the compacted, grazed soil, this behaviour is limited to patches of "high vegetation".

Like isopods, amphipods have a brood pouch in which the juveniles, and are live-bearing.

### Study design

On a plot of about 50 m2 on the grazed salt marsh, animals are collected ideally once every four (in summer) or 6 (in winter). A cylinder (diameter 15 cm) is placed on a piece of cow dung in the low vegetation, which is a hot spot in low vegetation patches, and all animals are collected in 70% ethanol.

All animals are inspected under a microscope. We record gender (or juvenile, for which this is not possible), the number of antennal segments (an indicator of age, as one is added every moult), and length of the first body segment (pereon 1, as an indicator of body size). For females, we record the stage of the brood pouch (we can identify four levels, of which only the fourth is reproductively active), and, for fully reproductive females, brood size (if present) and the stage of the brood pouch (we can identify three levels).

## Statistical models

One of the variables I want to look into is the proportion of fully reproductive females in the samples, for which I want to know whether there are seasonality and trend. Here are the data:

```
brood_pouch <- data.frame(
  date = c("2015-07-08","2015-08-20","2015-10-07","2015-12-10","2016-02-26",
       "2016-04-29","2016-06-26","2016-07-12","2016-08-13","2016-09-29",
       "2016-11-29","2017-03-03","2017-04-25","2017-06-17","2017-07-11",
       "2017-08-13","2017-10-03","2017-11-29","2018-03-14","2018-04-29",
       "2018-06-17","2018-12-07"),
  n = c(101, 57, 75, 95, 118, 203, 197, 134, 77, 175, 314, 236, 64, 171, 103, 
    288, 49, 61, 133, 51, 75, 154),
  proportion = c(0.900990099009901, 0.210526315789474, 0, 0, 0, 
             0.108374384236453, 0.903553299492386, 0.985074626865672, 
             0.246753246753247, 0.0171428571428571, 0, 0, 0.03125, 
             0.906432748538012, 0.300970873786408, 0.197916666666667, 
             0.0612244897959184, 0, 0, 0.176470588235294, 0.986666666666667, 
             0.00649350649350649)
)
```

As can be seen in the figure below, reproductively active females are abundant in summer but absent in winter.

[image]

Were it a generalised linear model, I would create separate variables of `year` and `month`, and create the following model:

```
glm(proportion ~ year * month, data = brood_pouch, 
                             weight = n_total, family = binomial)
```

where weight is the number of individuals that make up each proportion.

With a generalised additive model, I would expect to create a similar model, where in this case there would be clear seasonality but no clear trend.

I have been looking at the `gam` package and the `prophet` package, but they seem to operate on single data points per date.

Comment: There is a python package for irregular time series https://traces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  (not tested)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have no experience with python and all my data are in R already, so I would prefer to use R. I realised I can also use the list of all females with their reproductive state (0 or 1) with `family = binomial`, in which case I can skip the entire `weight` factor. That seems to work. I still need to figure out what to model then, because `date` is highly significant, but I do not know how to decompose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this with a GAM is to set up a model that decompose time into different components. In this case, you want a seasonal component, potentially a trend even if the data don't seem to have one, and then some remainder, which we will assume for now is independent noise such that given the model we have random draws from a binomial distribution with expectation given by the fitted values of the model.

Here is one way to achieve this using *mgcv*.

First you need to convert the `date` variable into something useful; initially a `Date` classed object and then we process that to get information about the day of year (week of year would also work), the year, which we also cast as a factor for one of the models we'll look at.

```
brood_pouch <- transform(brood_pouch,
                         date = as.Date(as.character(date)))
brood_pouch <- transform(brood_pouch,
                         doy   = as.numeric(format(date, '%j')),
                         year  = as.numeric(format(date, '%Y')),
                         fyear = as.factor(format(date, '%Y')))
```

The simplest reasonable model might be

```
m1 <- gam(proportion ~ fyear + s(doy), data = brood_pouch, method = 'REML',
          weights = n, family = binomial)
```

which has a seasonal smooth plus a different mean effect for each year. Extending this model to include separate seasonal smooths for each year, we have:

```
m2 <- gam(proportion ~ fyear + s(doy, by = fyear, k = 5), data = brood_pouch, 
          method = 'REML', weights = n, family = binomial)
```

And the full blown model with the long term trend modelled smoothly and the seasonal smooth allowed to vary with the trend would be given by

```
m3 <- gam(proportion ~ te(year, doy, k = c(3,6)), data = brood_pouch,
          method = 'REML', weights = n, family = binomial)
```

Of these three, there is a clear preference for `m2`:

```
> AIC(m1, m2 ,m3)
         df      AIC
m1 11.23595 169.6490
m2 14.99039 114.4300
m3 14.43998 130.7556
```

but there are some issues with that model that a proper analysis might try to tackle.

You can also model the trend as a `s(Date)`, but that won't decompose the data into seasonal effects plus change between years, and you'll need to increase `k` to get a flexible enough spline to model all the data in a single shot.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would be inclined to run `anova.gam(m2)`, which, according to the manual, is comparable to `drop1()`. This shows a clear year effect and clear doy effect for all years. Am I right to conclude that (1) there is clear seasonality in the proportion of reproductively active females in each year, and (2) there is a clear difference in the proportion of reproductively active females between years? Does the clear year effect mean there is a trend, like in time series analysis, or merely that there are differences between years?

Comment: You need to be careful with comparisons using `anova()` when models are fitted using 'REML' because these models have different "fixed" effects. You should refit the models with `method = 'ML'` I think if you want to do this comparison. I think you can claim 1), but I don't think you can be so bold on 2). All that the model with separate smooths per year is telling you in the summary is that it is unlikely to have gotten the smooth you did under the null hypothesis that each smooth was a flat line at 0.

Comment: I'd want to look at differences between smooths (which can be done using the model, eg: a blog [post](https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/10/difference-splines-i/) of mine), if I you wanted to make judgements about how clear the differences were; in the shape of the seasonality, when in particular etc.

Comment: As for "trend", the statistical definition is just that there are differences in the mean, or level, over time. This model suggests that there are, but we've only been able to model that trend as a different mean per year. So there is a statistical trend, but that might not mean what your readers/reviewers think it means.

Comment: Clear. So the `year` effect says there is a clear difference in the proportion between any of the years (classic anova). Would converting it to an ordinal factor (2015<2016<2017<2018) and finding a clear difference not suggest a trend? If not, I could show [https://i.postimg.cc/Kc7BFgMD/screenshot-1552031847.png](this figure) to clarify there is a clear year effect, but no trend.

Comment: You'd probably want to plot the estimated means + SEs as the parameterisation used above is for a given year relative to the reference year. If you make the factor ordinal, then that will change the meaning of the `by` term, so make sure that if you do that you use a regular factor for the `by` smooth. You can do post-hoc comparisons of years like you would with ANOVA using the *multcomp* pkg, but you need to create the contrasts for the comparisons yourself.

Comment: From [this post](https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/12/14/difference-splines-ii/#fn1) of yours, I get that you use an ordered factor to compare against a reference (the first order). I understand why you suggest to use the non-ordered variant for the parametric part (easier to interpret). However, I was hoping ordered factors would allow simply finding the "trend", i.e. whether there is a clear overall increase or decrease over time. That is what I would be interested in, not pairwise differences.

Comment: With `glm`s I never use `summary()`, but rather compare models where explanatory variables are dropped (`drop1()`, or `anova()` on both models). For instance, in [this paper](https://www-sciencedirect-com.vu-nl.idm.oclc.org/science/article/pii/S0020751915003306), I used `glm`s with *numeric* explanatory variables, and a clear effect simply states positive or negative trend (Fig. 3 is a good example). I never did this with ordinal variables, so I'm not sure if they would hold up in `glm`s anyway.

Comment: If you just want to fit the trend then the "factor" `by` smooth that I showed above and in the previous post in the series you mentioned is what you want. What `gam()` is doing is estimating an entirely separate smoother (they have their own smoothness parameters, but share the same set of basis functions) for each level of the factor. An *ordered* factor fits a different trend per level of the ordered factor it's just not as direct as the straight factor version.

Comment: With the factor version, whether the function is = 0 (Wald-like tests, a la `glm()`) is directly read off from the output from `summary()`. If you want to know if `m2` is better than `m1` (a single seasonal smooth, different means per year) then `AIC(m1, m2)` is a good option. The math underlying the `anova()` method for multiple *mgcv* models is approximate and you need to use `method = 'ML'` for it to make any sense. I would use `summary()` + plots of the smooths, then `AIC()`m then `anova()` in order of preference for comparing these models.

Comment: Thanks! Using `AIC(m1, m2, m3)` makes sense to find the most appropriate model. In this case, it is m2, suggesting there is evidence for a trend, and different smoothing for each year. `summary(m2)` shows significance of the year factor as the first level (2015) compared to all others, similar to `glm`s. That does not tell me whether there is an overall trend, does it?

Comment: Would it make sense to use `anova.gam()` on two models, and also include `gam(proportion ~ 1)`, `gam(proportion ~ fyear` and `gam(proportion ~ s(doy)` to `AIC()`, to find out the effects of year and doy? (comparing models with and without fyear would give the effect of fyear).

Comment: It makes sense to use `anova()` on a GAM the test it performs is a little anti-conservative, the models need to be nested, and you have to estimate them with `method = 'ML'` when we'd prefer `'REML'`. Models don't need to be nested for AIC, but I don't see much point in not including `fyear` as that's how your data were collected. Note that those aren't "finding out" the effects of those terms; the effect of `fyear` is different in a model with only `fyear` and one where it *and* other terms are in the model. You need `fyear` if you have a `by` smooth so I'm not seeing the reason to test this.

Comment: Oh, I did not know stepwise model selection was considered outdated---seems I need to up my game. I will investigate which test statistics I am supposed to report when I use AIC. Thankfully your elaborate answer cover most of that already :).